# limit failed login attemps for different login page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I don't use the default WordPress login page but a custom one. I use easy digital downloads so I just add this shortcode to a page and the login is created: [edd_login]
I receive brute force attacks and did many security measures but I want to limit failed login attempts on this page. All plugins and codes that I found work on the default Wordpress login page but not this custom one. Is there a solution like a custom code who works on any login page...?

Comment: I [can't find](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/limit-failed-login-attemps-in-edd/) a way to do it without creating some custom code or possible JavaScript hack, but if you happen to be behind Cloudflare, you could create a page rule to enable attack mode or something on that page. Not a fix, but it would perhaps be temporary mitigation until something better can be found/created.

Comment: I did find [reCAPTCHA for Easy Digital Downloads](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recaptcha-for-easy-digital-downloads/). It's outdated and apparently doesn't support reCAPTCHA v2, but it may be something to pursue (?).

Comment: Not sure if it works with custom pages, but have a look at iThemes Security https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/

Comment: If I don't find a custom code, I think I will work but the default Wordpress login page where the code is available and works